# How can I call an Objective-c static method asynchronously?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, static-methods

How can I call a static method asynchronously?

```
+ (void) readDataFromServerAndStoreToDatabase
{
     //do stuff here
     //might take up to 10 seconds
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a static method.  This is an example of a class method which is sent to the class, not an instance.  Note how it is still sent to something.  That should give you a clue how to do what you want (or read mipadi's answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use an `NSThread`:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(readDataFromServerAndStoreToDatabase)
                         toTarget:[MyClass class]
                       withObject:nil];
```

Comment: Don't know why this was voted down.  It succinctly and quite directly answered the question.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to accomplish concurrency in objective-C, depending on the environment you're running in. pthreads, NSThreads, NSOperations, GCD & blocks all have their place. You should read Apple's "Concurrency Programming Guide" for whichever platform you're targeting.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the broad choice of options, and the relevant guide

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000311-CHDEBGEC) against the class object. Suppose you have

```
@interface MyClass:NSObject{
....
}
+ (void) readAndStoreDataToDatabase;
@end
```

and then do

```
NSThread*thread=[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(readAndStoreDataToDatabase)
                                           target:[MyClass class]
                                       withObject:nil ];
```

Note that the class object of a class inheriting from `NSObject` is an `NSObject`, so you can pass it to these methods. See by yourself by running this program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(){
    NSAutoreleasePool*pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString* foo=@"foo";
    if([foo isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]){
        NSLog(@"%@",@"YES");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%@",@"NO");     
    }
    if([[NSString class] isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]){
        NSLog(@"%@",@"YES");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%@",@"NO");     
    }
    [pool drain];
}
```

The point is that, in Objective-C, class methods (which are called static methods in C++) are just standard methods sent to the class object. For more on class objects, see these great blog posts by [Hamster](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html) and by [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html).

Comment: Correct, but I'd wager that the questioner has no idea how much rope they've just been handed. ;)

Comment: I do, I have done a lot of threading before, I just didn't know it was possible to call a static method through a thread, so the keyword here was [MyClass class]

Comment: There's no such thing as a `static` method in Objective-C :) They are `class methods`, and they are sent `dynamically` to the class object. Once you get that, it's perfectly natural that you can do this.